# Accessing a specific item of a tuple from a listbox of tuples

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listbox, tuples

i've got a problem accessing the items of a tuple that is inserted to a listbox, so i can insert them into a database seperately.

[image]

To make it easier for you see the code below.

```
private void btnInsertToResult(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button butoni = sender as Button;

        if (butoni.Name == "btnMonday")
        {
            listRezultati.Items.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(Monday.Name, cmbMondayFrom.Text, cmbMondayTo.Text));
        }

        if (butoni.Name == "btnTuesday")
        {
            listRezultati.Items.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(Tuesday.Name, cmbTuesdayFrom.Text, cmbTuesdayTo.Text));
        }

        if (butoni.Name == "btnWednesday")
        {
            listRezultati.Items.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(Wednesday.Name, cmbWednesdayFrom.Text, cmbWednesdayTo.Text));
        }
        if (butoni.Name == "btnThursday")
        {
            listRezultati.Items.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(Thursday.Name, cmbThursdayFrom.Text, cmbThursdayTo.Text));
        }
        if (butoni.Name == "btnFriday")
        {
            listRezultati.Items.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(Friday.Name, cmbFridayFrom.Text, cmbFridayTo.Text));
        }
        if (butoni.Name == "btnSaturday")
        {
            listRezultati.Items.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(Saturday.Name, cmbSaturdayFrom.Text, cmbSaturdayTo.Text));
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact problem? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get items using:

```
var list = listBox.Items.Cast<Tuple<string, string, string>>().ToList();
```

Also you can insert them in a `BindingList<Tuple<string, string, string>>` and bind the `ListBox` to that list by assigning the binding list to `DataSource` of `ListBox`. This way, you can simply add or remove items to the binding list, and the changes will be shown immediately in `ListBox`.

**Note:**
If you want to save them in database, consider using a `DataTable` or an entity framework model class, then you can simply save them to database.